# Let $A$ be a given matrix over an algebraically closed field. If $U(B) := AB−BA$ is diagonalizable, then so is $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

After solving a similar problem in Hoffman and Kunze, I'm trying this one for a long time, but I didn't get success. I tried use the fact that the eigenvalues of $U$ are $\lambda_i-\lambda_j$ with $1\leq i,j\leq n$ where $A$ is $n$ x $n$ and $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$. Of course, $A$ has an eigenvector because the field is algebraically closed. But, even though knowing these facts I'm troubling in prove the main question about $A$ be diagonalizable. Any suggestions will be appreciated! Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Does this hold for any $B$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz He doesn't mean $U(B)$ is diagonalizable, he means the operator $U$.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thanks.

Comment: The claim is true if $A$ is a single Jordan block... This suggests to look at the Jordan cannonical form.

Comment: I thought about $U$ has at least $n$  eigenvectors associated with the null eigenvalue of $U$, and thus $AB_k=B_kA$ for at least $n$ distinct eigenvectors of $B_k$ of $U$. Thus using that  to yield $n$ distinct eigenvectors to $A$... but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** The idea here is that you can construct a generalised eigenspace of $U$ from a generalised eigenspace of $A$. Suppose $A$ is *not* diagonalisable. Then for some eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$, we have $Ax=\lambda x$ and $Ay=\lambda y+x$ for some eigenvector $x$ and some generalised eigenvector $y$. Now, let $z$ be a *left* eigenvector of $A$. Define $B=xz^T$ and $C=yz^T$. What are $U(C)$ and $U^2(C)$?